# What is difference between useQuery and initiate in RTK query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

When we are inside the selector, in order not to violate the rules of hooks, we can use the RTK query endpoint as follows:

**1)useQuery**

```
  const data = datsApi.endpoints.getData.useQuery(someProps)
```

**2)initiate**

```
  const data = await dispatch(datsApi.endpoints.getData.initiate(someProps))
  const { data } = data
```

But what is the difference between them, and when is it better to use each of the examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initiate()` is a Redux [async thunk](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#fetching-data-with-createasyncthunk) that triggers fetching data for that endpoint with that cache key argument.

The `useQuery` hooks automatically dispatch that thunk as needed when a component mounts or you change the cache key argument to the hook, and also contain a `useSelector` call to retrieve that cache entry's data for the component.

95% of the time, the `useQuery` hook is all you need.

The `initiate()` thunk is really only needed when you have to trigger a request outside of a component, or in some other imperative logic.